# how can i extract a string or pattern from a result set

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I included an oracle command

*$DOMAIN_HOME/reports/bin/rwdiag.sh -findall*

in a linux script that does a check of our env and returns a sample output below

- (1) Name = rep_wls_reports_orclas4t : Type = server : Host =
- (2) Name = rep_wls_reports_ias10t_frasinst_1 : Type = server : Host
  =
- (3) Name = rptsvr_orclas5p_frasinst_1 : Type = server : Host =
- ...

(a list of existing report servers available for use in our ERP)

I am trying to extract just the portion **Name = rep****** and report just that only in my output.  How can I use sed and/or grep to achieve this.

Many thanks for any assistance.

Regards

Comment: I am not sure I totally understand exactly what the output you would like is. Could you give specific examples of your actual input and desired output in your question?

Comment: You mean like `grep -o 'Name\s=\s[^:]*' file`? (or `rwdiag.sh -findall | grep -o 'Name\s=\s[^:]*'`) Or, if you want the `(1)..` before `"Name"` as well, you can simply use `grep -o '^[^:]*'`

Comment: thanks guys.  Problem is I get 2 different result sets - result set 1) (1) Name = rep_wls_reports_orclas4t : Type = server : Host = xxxxxxxxx. result set 2) (1) rep_wls_reports_orclas7d : Type = server : Host = NA. Using awk won't cover both cases as I can't tell what is $2. @DavidC.Rankin worked but inconsistent output. Is there a versatile gred/sed I can use to just extract "rep_xxxxx"?

Comment: Hmm, the results should be consistent. The first (longer) command removes the `(x).` from the beginning and the `grep -o '^[^:]*'` command just reads from the beginning to the first `':'`. The results of the two separate commands are intended to be different, but using either one should provide consistent results.

Comment: For that I would use `sed 's/^.*Name\s=\s\(\w\w*\).*$/\1/' file` which would give, e.g. `rep_wls_reports_ias10t_frasinst_1`

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin. `grep -o '^[^:]*'` on result set 1 returns **(1) Name = rep_wls_reports_orclas4t**, but on result set 2 returns **(1)  rep_wls_reports_orclas7d** . `grep -o 'Name\s=\s[^:]*'` returns **Name = rep_wls_reports_orclas4t** . To make the result consistent for both result sets 1 & 2 (see prior comment) , how do I tweak either to take out ** Name =" ** so I am just left with **rep_wls_reports_orclas4t**. Thanks

Comment: You can also simply use `awk '{print $4}' file` to get the same information

Comment: Many thanks @DavidC.Rankin. Sorry I have another question. So for result set 1 , `sed 's/^.*Name\s=\s\(\w\w*\).*$/\1/'` would give me the desired result.  What can I use for use for result set 2 i.e. (1) rep_wls_reports_orclas7d : Type = server : Host = NA to achieve the same result - extract **rep xxxx**. awk may not work as col 4 may vary? Kinda new to the linux scripting.  If you don't mind, can you also explain the sed command. Thanks

Comment: `sed 's/^[^)][^)]*\s\(\w\w*\).*$/\1/'`

Comment: `sed 's/^[^)][^)]*\s\(\w\w*\).*$/\1/'` didn't work. It still returned **(1) rep_wls_reports_orclas7d : Type = server : Host = NA**

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `awk`

```
$DOMAIN_HOME/reports/bin/rwdiag.sh -findall | awk -F' ' $'{print $2,$3,$4}'
```

With this command you use the string like a list separate by space(defined with -F).